# Cassanra-Medusa ERROR: This error happened during the backup: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nodetool'

Tags: cassandra

I am using cassandra 3.11 with cassandra-medusa 0.4.1
Cassandra located :/usr/share/cassandra

It's showing:

medusa backup --backup-name=22012020

```
[2020-01-22 16:38:38] INFO: Monitoring provider is noop
[2020-01-22 16:38:38] WARNING: is ccm : 0
[2020-01-22 16:38:38] INFO: Creating snapshot
[2020-01-22 16:38:38] INFO: Saving tokenmap and schema
[2020-01-22 16:38:38] INFO: Node local does not have latest backup
[2020-01-22 16:38:38] INFO: Starting backup
[2020-01-22 16:38:38] ERROR: This error happened during the backup: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nodetool'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/medusa/backup.py", line 274, in main
    cassandra, node_backup, storage, differential_mode, config)
```

Answer (score 2):

Medusa doesn't have an option to specify location of the `nodetool` command, so it just expects that it's available in the `PATH` - you need to add path to the Cassandra installation to the `PATH`, and Medusa will find it.